# How to insert cell values before existing cell values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have a code in VBA, which copies 2 columns of existing values below an another sheet's similar data. I want to slightly change the VBA code to, that if the cell of value another sheet (C3) is TRUE, then it copies that data to the beginning of the existing data instead (the beginning is A1 and B1).
I have this data in a worksheet:

```
-Q-  -R-
156  F5
486  T9
695  H3
```

I have an already existing data in an another worksheet:

```
-A-  -B-
695  E6
326  T8
326  Q9
```

I need to paste the new values before the existing values if the value of C3 on another sheet is TRUE

```
-A-  -B-
156  F5
486  T9
695  H3
695  E6
326  T8
326  Q9
```

I have the code to copy the data to the end of the existi8ng data, I just need to expand this to be able to insert the data to the beginning of the data, essentially shifting all existing values below the new ones if C3 is TRUE. (the Values I need to copy is in the "Nastavit D" sheet (Q and R), I need to paste them into the "Chain (A and B), and the C3 TRUE cell is on the "Nedotykat sa!!!" sheet) (If C3 is FALSE, I need to copy it to the end of the existing data, which my code already does, without the C3 check.)

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Dim x, y(), I As Long, ii As Long

    If Sheets("Nastavit D").[Q2] = "" Then Exit Sub
    x = Sheets("Nastavit D").[Q2:R1000]
    For I = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
        If x(I, 1) <> "" Then
            ReDim Preserve y(1 To 2, 1 To I)
            For ii = 1 To 2
                y(ii, I) = x(I, ii)
            Next
        Else: Exit For
        End If
    Next
    With Sheets("Chain")
        .Cells(.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(y, 2), 2) = Application.Transpose(y)
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Not fully tested, but I think you get the idea.

```
If Worksheets("Nedotykat sa!!!").Range("C3") Then

    With Sheets("Chain")

        Dim originalData as Variant
        originalData = .Range(.Range("A2"),.Range("B2").End(xlDown)) 'grab original data

        .cells(2,1).Resize(Ubound(y,2),2) = Application.Transpose(y) 'write new data
        .cells(.rows.count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(ubound(originalData,2),ubound(originalData,1)) = originalData 'write original data at the bottom

    End With

Else

    With Sheets("Chain")
        .Cells(.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(y, 2), 2) = Application.Transpose(y)
    End With

End If
```

Comment: It gives me a Syntax Error, on this line: originalData = .Range(.Range("A2"),.Range("B2").End(xlDown) 'grab original data

Comment: @TomasPerlecky - sorry, i forgot the last closing parens. fixed now

Comment: Thanks for the fix, however, now it says Type mismatch: .Cells(.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(y, 2), 2) = Application.Transpose(y)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in <strike>two</strike> three ways. First, you can copy and insert using Excels built-in methods.
 It is as simple as below:

**Edit1:** I adjusted finding of last row. This will find the last cell in Column Q with value, if no cell was found, last row - `lr` will be set to 1000.

```
Dim lr As Long
With Sheets("Nastavit D")
  '// simply find the last row, can be done in various ways //
  'lr = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   On Error Resume Next
   lr = .Range("Q:Q").Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then lr = 1000
   On Error GoTo 0

  .Range("Q2:R" & lr).Copy '// copy the data //
End With
'// insert data in target range //
Sheets("Chain").Range("A2").Insert xlDown
```

Another is using array but I still use the insert method of Excel like below (hybrid).

```
Dim lr As Long, v
With Sheets("Nastavit D")
  '// same as above, get the last row
  lr = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  v = .Range("Q2:R" & lr) '// pass to array //
End With

With Sheets("Chain")
  '// insert a range the size of the array //
  .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2)).Insert xlDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
  '// dump array in the space created //
  .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(v, 1), UBound(v, 2)) = v
End With
```

If there is not requirement to do an array I'd suggest you do the first one.
The last approach is already provided, you dump both data in array as [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58600328/2685412).

Comment: These nearly work them as i want to, but both of them copies all of the rows (all 1000 of them, meaning even Blank cells.). Can they be modified to just copy the rows which contain a Value (They contain formulas too, but I dont want them to be copied)